# Selecting part of a string

Tags: jquery, regex, string

I have a jquery string, say x.

```
x = '##_##Donec commodo imperdiet diam##_###, eget porttitor nisi blandit facilisis. Morbi vitae lectus id nunc ultricies tincidunt.';
```

I want to select the part of string between the ##_## and ##_### i.e. "Donec commodo imperdiet diam" from the above example.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `##_##(.*?)##_###` or `#+_#+(.*?)#+_#+`, and grab the part you want from group index 1. Please do a search before asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can do:

```
var res = str.split('##_##')[1].split('##_###')[0];
```

Comment: This i thought, but i am sure there is a more efficient solution than this.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
var myString = "##_##Donec commodo imperdiet diam##_###, eget porttitor nisi blandit facilisis. Morbi vitae lectus id nunc ultricies tincidunt.";
var myRegexp = /##_##([^#]*)##_###/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
console.log(match[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the more generic code how to get a text between 2 different (but constant) delimiters in JS:

```js
teststr = '##_##Donec commodo imperdiet diam##_###, eget porttitor nisi blandit facilisis. Morbi vitae lectus id nunc ultricies tincidunt.##_##More text##_### here.';
function GetSubstrs(istr) {
  var res = [];
  var start_pos = istr.indexOf('##_##');
  while (start_pos > -1)
  {
    var end_pos = istr.indexOf('##_###',start_pos + 5);
    var text_to_get = istr.substring(start_pos + 5,end_pos)
    res.push(text_to_get);
    start_pos = istr.indexOf('##_##', end_pos + 6);
  }
  return res;
}

alert(GetSubstrs(teststr));
```